# Unity Admon interstitial not showing on devices

Tags: unity-game-engine, admob, ads, banner, interstitial

I hope you can help me.
So basiclly my code works in the Unity editor perfectly i have 3 scenec. Menu / Level / Restart
Menu has a banner bottom. This works on all devices (Android/iOS).
Play scene has also a Banner on the bottom and also works on all devices.
Now the Problem scene. I have a interstitial ad in the restart scene. This method gets invoked after 2 sec.
Unity Editor no problem, it displays the ad perfectly.
Android/iOS the ad doesnt show up + there is a Banner on the buttom but i dont have a banner script active in this scene. Any suggestions how i can show up my interstitial ad on Android/iOS?
Some people say its not working by testing devices only when you upload to the Playstore/Appstore.
Is this right?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.